# How to serialise many to one relationship from the many side hibernate jpa

Tags: json, hibernate, jpa, serialization

I have a many to one relationship in my hibernate models. There are many people with one role. I have another model "schools" with a one to many join with the people model.

Schools 1-* people *-1 role

I want to GET and POST to the schools model, which should contain a list of schools with many people each with one role. However I can not serialise the roles for people.

I need to be able to serialise from the many to one side (people-roles). However when I put @jsonmanagedreference on the many to one side, I get a "404 validation error" trying a POST. When I change it to a jsonbackreference it does not get serialised.

I have also tried using @jsonidentityinfo, after googling to try get a bidirectional relationship.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Role { ... }
```

However when I put this in both models I get infinite recursion and tomcat times out.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Have you tried adding `@JsonManagedReference` in many side (`people`) and `@JsonBackReference` in one side (`roles`) at the same time.

Comment: Yes. I still get the validation error.

Comment: can you post that error/exception and also `person` and `role` class

Comment: I tired in my example its working with using `@JsonManagedReference` and  `@JsonBackReference` at a time. post your class and the error that you getting

Comment: So you can do a jsonmanagedreference on a many to one and you can still do POSTS to update? I will have access to the code again tomorrow and will post my models.